# MAMP incorrect PHP version

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php, mamp

I have MAMP installed and when I start the server I choose PHP 5.6.1, but when I run `php -v` in terminal in my `MAMP/htdocs/project` folder it shows 5.5.36 and if I run composer install it throws error

> doctrine/annotations v1.3.0 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP
>   version (5.5.36) does not satisfy that requirement.

Moreover, if I run it in `MAMP/htdocs` it shows 5.6.31.

What am I doing wrong and where should I update the PHP?

Comment: Im guessing because your are running your local terminal and it shows the php version that is mapped to that PATH variable

Comment: you can pin point the problem reading this answer https://serverfault.com/questions/58346/how-to-determine-which-php-is-being-used

Comment: That's true. But how to solve the problem and run 5.6 for the project?

Comment: May be a confuse beetween cli (console) and web bin look at the echo $PATH

Comment: @SvetoslavDimitrov your project is probably running 5.6, but your local terminal is running your local PHP, and so is composer. Can you run a terminal within the MAMP environment?

Comment: @Ice76 so my /project is looking at usr/local/bin that contains 5.5 and terminal is looking at /usr/local/php5/bin/php with 5.6. So how to make my project look at /usr/local/php5/bin/php?

Comment: @SvetoslavDimitrov there should be a settings file. if anything, you can just copythe php version 5.6 files into that directory

Answer (score 0):

MAMP uses a different version of PHP then your System. The MAMP version of PHP is usually installed to:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/bin/php
```

So, if you do:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/bin/php -v
```

You will get the correct version displayed.

If you edit the `~/.bash_profile` file on your machine to add the following lines (and then reopen terminal):

```
alias php='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/bin/php'
export MAMP_PHP=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/bin
export PATH=$MAMP_PHP:$PATH
```

(if you already have `PATH` setup in `~/.bash_profile`, just append `:$MAMP_PHP` to the end)

You can then do:

```
php -v
```

get the correct version. And then you can run `composer install` or `composer update` with the correct version of PHP.

This is what I have setup in my `.bash_profile` for reference.

[image]